# XAMPP sendmail shows sent in the log, but can't receive anywhere

Tags: email, xampp, sendmail.exe

My configuration:

Windows 8, newest XAMPP 3.2.1, Gmail account.
I am trying to configure sendmail.

in php.ini:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = info@favsync.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
extension=php_openssl.dll (not commented)
```

in sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=correct_email
auth_password=correct_password
force_sender=correct_email
```

also tried:

```
account Gmail
tls on
tls_certcheck off
host smtp.gmail.com
from correct_email
auth on
user correct_email
password correct_password

port 587

account default : Gmail
```

in the php_mail_log I see this:

> [06-Mar-2014 01:57:10 Europe/Berlin] mail() on [C:\test\test.php:9]:
>   To: e1630241@drdrb.com -- Headers: From: test@gmail.com  Reply-To:
>   test@gmail.com  X-Mailer: PHP/5.5.9

So it does look like it was sent, but I don't receive it. tried to different emails, gmail, 10 minute mail, my ISP mail, nothing works.

And I am using a standard php mail script:

```
<?php
$to      = 'e1630241@drdrb.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: test@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: test@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

PLEASE help, I am really frustrated and really wasted lots of time. It's like they try to make every step more difficult than it should be..

Thanks

Comment: the php mail log is basically irrelevant. It just shows that PHP handed the email over to your mail server. in real life terms, you walked your letter down to the mailbox on the street corner and threw it into the box. PHP has **NO** way of knowing what happened to the letter after that. maybe the mailbox got run over and the letter destroyed. You need to check the mail server's own logs.

Comment: something I've noticed is that when I messed up the sendmail.ini (just filled in some wrong smtp server) it was still putting the same entry in the php_mail_log. so this log doesn't give any useful info apparently. Any other log I can check?

Comment: the actual mail server log. e.g. `/var/log/maillog` on a unix-ish system.

Comment: Marc, thanks. how do I check the logs of the mail server?

Comment: it's a localhost and it's windows..